# phonegap + ionic using Content-Security-Policy to load maps.googleapis.com, how to?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, firebase, phonegap-plugins, content-security-policy

i have tried many ways of loading google maps and firebaseio without success:
this is what i have now:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com;
  script-src 'self' https://maps.googleapis.com/* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';
  style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';">
```

and i get:

```
Refused to load the script 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' https://maps.googleapis.com/* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'".

Refused to load the script 'https://test.firebaseio.com/.lp?start=t&ser=79549912&cb=1&v=5' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' https://maps.googleapis.com/* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'".
```

any ideas what am i doing wrong?

Comment: tried `'https://maps.googleapis.com/*'` rather than `https://maps.googleapis.com/*`

Comment: @Sushant, nope. i get `The source list for Content Security Policy directive 'script-src' contains an invalid source: ''https://maps.googleapis.com/*''. It will be ignored. `

Comment: fwiw scheme://host/* isn't a valid CSP pattern. `https://maps.googleapis.com` is what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

this did the trick :)

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
          content="default-src *;
               script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'
                           127.0.0.1:*
                           http://*.google.com
                           http://*.gstatic.com
                           http://*.googleapis.com
                           http://*.firebaseio.com
                           https://*.google.com
                           https://*.gstatic.com
                           https://*.googleapis.com
                           https://*.firebaseio.com
                           ;
               style-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline'
                          127.0.0.1
                           http://*.google.com
                           http://*.gstatic.com
                           http://*.googleapis.com
                           http://*.firebaseio.com
                           https://*.google.com
                           https://*.gstatic.com
                           https://*.googleapis.com
                           https://*.firebaseio.com
">
```

and the google script `<script src="https://maps-api-ssl.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>`

Answer (score 1):

for development without any restrictions use:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
      content="default-src * 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'">
```

Comment: Your solution is **only** for developing, but not for production. XSS is not a joke.